# C# get text from textbox vscode

Tags: c#, forms, textbox

I'm building a script in c# and I want to get a text from a textbox, but that's not going well, I don't know exactly how to get the text as it's...

````
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private TextBox textBox1;
    public void FormLayout()
    {
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.textBox1 = new TextBox();
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        string lingua = this.textBox1.Text;
    }
}

public class RegisterScriptMenu
{

    public static Form1 form = new Form1();
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        form.FormLayout();;
        Application.Run(form);
        return form.FormLayout().lingua;
    }

    [DeclareAction("Exporta_Traduzir")]
    public void MyFunctionAsAction1()
    {        
        string linguagem = Main();```
````

This in the end does not returns "linguagem" as the string I input in the textbox.
I'm new in c# so maybe that's easy and I just don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Main is void - that means you can not return a value. Second, you have two ; in your form.formLayout()

Try to fix this and check if it works, just try to create a Label to see if you get the value.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private TextBox textBox1;
    private Label label1;

    public void FormLayout()
    {
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.textBox1 = new TextBox();
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        string lingua = this.textBox1.Text;
    }
}

public class RegisterScriptMenu
{

    public static Form1 form = new Form1();
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        form.FormLayout();
        form.label1.Text = form.ligua;
        Application.Run(form);
    }

    [DeclareAction("Exporta_Traduzir")]
    public void MyFunctionAsAction1()
    {
       string linguagem = Main();
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. I've tried to do the Label and to get the text, but it's not showing up, I thought that could be cause I'm not clicking any button, so I tried to add a button, it wasn't successfully try hahahahaha.